# How to test graphical output of functions?

Tags: r, testing, graphics, plot, testthat

I am wondering how to test functions that produce graphics. I have a simple
plotting function `img`:

```
img <- function() {
  plot(1:10)
}
```

In my package I like to create a unit test for this function using `testthat`.
Because `plot` and its friends in *base graphics* just return `NULL` a simple
`expect_identical` is not working:

```
library("testthat")

## example for a successful test
expect_identical(plot(1:10), img()) ## equal (as expected)

## example for a test failure
expect_identical(plot(1:10, col="red"), img()) ## DOES NOT FAIL!
# (because both return NULL)
```

First I thought about plotting into a file and compare the md5 checksums to
ensure that the output of the functions is equal:

```
md5plot <- function(expr) {
  file <- tempfile(fileext=".pdf")
  on.exit(unlink(file))
  pdf(file)
  expr
  dev.off()
  unname(tools::md5sum(file))
}

## example for a successful test
expect_identical(md5plot(img()),
                 md5plot(plot(1:10))) ## equal (as expected)

## example for a test failure
expect_identical(md5plot(img()),
                 md5plot(plot(1:10, col="red"))) ## not equal (as expected)
```

That works well on Linux but not on Windows. Surprisingly
`md5plot(plot(1:10))` results in a new md5sum at each call.
Aside this problem I need to create a lot of temporary files.

Next I used `recordPlot` (first creating a null-device, call the plotting
function and record its output). This works as expected:

```
recPlot <- function(expr) {
  pdf(NULL)
  on.exit(dev.off())
  dev.control(displaylist="enable")
  expr
  recordPlot()
}

## example for a successful test
expect_identical(recPlot(plot(1:10)),
                 recPlot(img())) ## equal (as expected)

## example for a test failure
expect_identical(recPlot(plot(1:10, col="red")),
                 recPlot(img())) ## not equal (as expected)
```

Does anybody know a better way to test the graphical output of functions?

*EDIT*: regarding the points @josilber asks in his comments.

While the `recordPlot` approach works well you have to rewrite the whole plotting function in the unit test. That becomes complicated for complex plotting functions. It would be nice to have an approach that allows to store a file (`*.RData` or `*.pdf`, ...) which contains an image against you could compare in future tests. The `md5sum` approach isn't working because the md5sums differ on different platforms. Via `recordPlot` you could create an `*.RData` file but you could not rely on its format (from the `recordPlot` manual page):

> The format of recorded plots may change between R versions.
>        Recorded plots can *not* be used as a permanent storage format for
>        R plots.

Maybe it would be possible to store an image file (`*.png`, `*.bmp`, etc), import it and compare it pixel by pixel ...

*EDIT2*: The following code illustrate the desired reference file approach using svg as output. First the needed helper functions:

```
## plot to svg and return file contant as character
plot_image <- function(expr) {
  file <- tempfile(fileext=".svg")
  on.exit(unlink(file))
  svg(file)
  expr
  dev.off()
  readLines(file)
}

## the IDs differ at each `svg` call, that's why we simple remove them
ignore_svg_id <- function(lines) {
  gsub(pattern = "(xlink:href|id)=\"#?([a-z0-9]+)-?(?<![0-9])[0-9]+\"",
       replacement = "\\1=\"\\2\"", x = lines, perl = TRUE)
}

## compare svg character vs reference
expect_image_equal <- function(object, expected, ...) {
  stopifnot(is.character(expected) && file.exists(expected))
  expect_equal(ignore_svg_id(plot_image(object)),
               ignore_svg_id(readLines(expected)), ...)
}

## create reference image
create_reference_image <- function(expr, file) {
  svg(file)
  expr
  dev.off()
}
```

A test would be:

```
create_reference_image(img(), "reference.svg")

## create tests
library("testthat")

expect_image_equal(img(), "reference.svg") ## equal (as expected)
expect_image_equal(plot(1:10, col="red"), "reference.svg") ## not equal (as expected)
```

Sadly this is not working across different platforms. The order (and the names)
of the svg elements completely differs on Linux and Windows.

Similar problems exist for `png`, `jpeg` and `recordPlot`. The resulting files
differ on all platforms.

Currently the only working solution is the `recPlot` approach above. But therefore
I need to rewrite the whole plotting functions in my unit tests.

---

P.S.:
I am completley confused about the different md5sums on Windows. It seems they depending on the creation time of the temporary files:

```
# on Windows
table(sapply(1:100, function(x)md5plot(plot(1:10))))
#4693c8bcf6b6cb78ce1fc7ca41831353 51e8845fead596c86a3f0ca36495eacb
#                              40                               60
```

Comment: It seems like your `recordPlot` solution works well for your use case, but you then ask at the end of the question if anybody knows a better way to test. Could you elaborate on what you're looking for, aka why your current approach with `recordPlot` is not sufficient?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mango Solutions have published an open source package, `visualTest`, that does fuzzy matching of plots, to address this use case.

The package is on [github](https://github.com/MangoTheCat/visualTest), so install using:

```
devtools::install_github("MangoTheCat/visualTest")
library(visualTest)
```

Then use the function `getFingerprint()` to extract a finger print for each plot, and compare using the function `isSimilar()`, specifying a suitable threshold.

First, create some plots on file:

```
png(filename = "test1.png")
img()
dev.off()

png(filename = "test2.png")
plot(1:11, col="red")
dev.off()
```

The finger print is a numeric vector:

```
> getFingerprint(file = "test1.png")
 [1]  4  7  4  4 10  4  7  7  4  7  7  4  7  4  5  9  4  7  7  5  6  7  4  7  4  4 10
[28]  4  7  7  4  7  7  4  7  4  3  7  4  4  3  4  4  5  5  4  7  4  7  4  7  7  7  4
[55]  7  7  4  7  4  7  5  6  7  7  4  8  6  4  7  4  7  4  7  7  7  4  4 10  4  7  4

> getFingerprint(file = "test2.png")
 [1]  7  7  4  4 17  4  7  4  7  4  7  7  4  5  9  4  7  7  5  6  7  4  7  7 11  4  7
[28]  7  5  6  7  4  7  4 14  4  3  4  7 11  7  4  7  5  6  7  7  4  7 11  7  4  7  5
[55]  6  7  7  4  8  6  4  7  7  4  4  7  7  4 10 11  4  7  7
```

Compare using `isSimilar()`:

```
> isSimilar(file = "test2.png",
+           fingerprint = getFingerprint(file = "test1.png"),
+           threshold = 0.1
+ )
[1] FALSE
```

---

You can read more about the package at http://www.mango-solutions.com/wp/products-services/r-services/r-packages/visualtest/

Comment: Great! That is excatly what I was looking for! Unfortunately the package is not on CRAN yet but for most of my use cases that is fine.

Comment: Still not seeing `visualTest` on CRAN, but I do see `vdiffr` there: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vdiffr/index.html

Answer (score 7):

It's worth noting that the [vdiffr](https://github.com/lionel-/vdiffr) package also supports comparing plots. A nice feature is that it integrates with the testthat package -- it's actually used for testing in ggplot2 -- and it has an add-in for RStudio to help manage your testsuite.